# "this." code blank output, main function

Tags: java, function, this

why cant this block of code produce the output its supposed to? it should return :

1

42

MyThisTest a=42

the code output is blank. and whenever I set the curly brackets for 'public static void main(String[] args)' lots of red line errors pop up. Anyone knows how to work this...

```
public class MyThisTest {
public static void main(String[] args){}
private int a;

public MyThisTest() {
this(42); // calls the other constructor
}

public MyThisTest(int a) {
this.a = a; // assigns the value of the parameter a to the field of the same name
}

public void frobnicate() {
int a = 1;

System.out.println(a); // refers to the local variable a
System.out.println(this.a); // refers to the field a
System.out.println(this); // refers to this entire object
}

public String toString() {
return "MyThisTest a=" + a; // refers to the field a
}
}
```

Comment: You should add the language tag.

Answer (score 1):

Your main function is rather wrong. It should create a `MyThisTest` and call `frobnicate()` on it.

Something like

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   MyThisTest myThisTest;
   myThisTest.frobnicate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss any operation in your main function:

```
public static void main(String[] args){}
```

should probably be:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    MyThisTest thisTest = new MyThisTest();

    thisTest.frobnicate();
}
```

The main function is the function which is called when you start the program.
If you don't do anything in there, nothing will happen. And therefore the output in your original code keeps blank.

Answer (score 0):

Main method is the starting point for a java program, you need to initialize the object there. Constructors which you have defined can not be called until you initialize the object. The method frobnicate is also object level method, it can only be called on an instance. You should do all these in main method (as already explained by others)